# Build fails on server if SpecificVersion is not set to false

Tags: tfsbuild

Visual studio 2015 TFS.

I have come across a scenarios where if below mentioned property is not set to false and if team takes latest code and builds locally... no one get error...build is successful for all. 
However, When we build on the server, it fails.

```
Proprty name: <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
File name: Any cs project file
```

edit: This property pertains to the dll that we reference in the project.

How this can be avoided ? Can we use any settings or tool in TFS that will validate all such settings, trigger the build on checks in and send notification if build fails?

Comment: Which build are you using? The old XAML build or the new vNext build? And since it fails on the tfs server build, what's  the detail error you got?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT - we are using old xaml build and error message we get is below - Could not load file or assembly 'name of dll, Version=x.x.xxx.xxx, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.   this is due to the build # we are triggering on server is different.

Comment: looks like your server dll version is not match your local dll version.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the `<SpecificVersion>` value with true, you need to make sure the version of your server dll and local dll is the same.

If you want your local dll be used for TFS server build, the simplest way is checking that dll in version control and download it in build agent working folder.

If you want your local dll be used for TFS server build, you need to modify the version info of that dll including PublicKeyToken in the `XX.csproj` file. This could be done through a powershell script before msbuild in your XAML build definition.